# How to use AsyncHTTPProvider in web3py?

Tags: web3.py, python, async

I am trying to use the AsyncHTTPProvider in a project, and here is my test code:

```
import asyncio
from web3 import Web3
import asyncio

async def main():
  w3 = Web3(Web3.AsyncHTTPProvider("http://127.0.0.1:8545"))
  coinbase = await w3.eth.coinbase
  print(coinbase)

if __name__ == "__main__":
  asyncio.run(main())
```

i couldn't find any examples online of people using the AsyncHTTPProvider, even in the web3py github I couldn't really find an example that I could understand (reading pull requests of large libraries is very tedious)

When I run this code, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\V\Desktop\STATS BOT\LP\lp.py", line 10, in <module>
asyncio.run(main())
File "C:\Users\V\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 44, 
inrun
return loop.run_until_complete(main)
File "C:\Users\V\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 642, 
in run_until_complete
return future.result()
File "C:\Users\V\Desktop\STATS BOT\LP\lp.py", line 6, in main
coinbase = await w3.eth.coinbase
File "C:\Users\V\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\web3\eth.py", line 
282, in coinbase
return self.get_coinbase()
File "C:\Users\V\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\web3\module.py", line 
57, in caller
result = w3.manager.request_blocking(method_str, params, error_formatters)
File "C:\Users\V\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\web3\manager.py", 
line 154, in request_blocking
response = self._make_request(method, params)
File "C:\Users\V\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\web3\manager.py", 
line 133, in _make_request
return request_func(method, params)
TypeError: 'coroutine' object is not callable
sys:1: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'AsyncBaseProvider.request_func' was never awaited

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I'm trying to create a telegram bot that use would be available to tip each other with specific token but I faced with issues while sending a token thought the bot and waiting for conformation my bot is getting freeze and would not accept any commands until I receive a response from a network.

```
signed_tx =  w3.eth.account.signTransaction(tx, walletData['privet_hex'])
transaction_event = await message.answer("<code>Transaction sent!\nWaiting for conformation... </code>",
                                         disable_notification=True,
                                         parse_mode="html")
tx_hash =  w3.eth.sendRawTransaction(signed_tx.rawTransaction)
recipt_hash =  w3.eth.wait_for_transaction_receipt(binascii.hexlify(tx_hash).decode()) 
 # ^---- Here where its freeze
hash = binascii.hexlify(tx_hash).decode()
```